# Repeat last isearch with all parameters

Tags: isearch

Everyone knows you can repeat the last I-search with <kbd>C-s C-s</kbd>, but that doesn't preserve all the parameters from the last search. As a concrete example, I often use symbol I-search (<kbd>M-s _</kbd>), and typing <kbd>M-s _ C-s</kbd> is a fair bit cumbersome when going through a lot of matches.

It would be nice if <kbd>C-s C-s</kbd> could see if the last I-search was a symbol search and reactivate that. Similar things can of course be said for other I-search states, like regex searches (though that isn't quite as cumbersome to do manually to begin with).

Is there a way to do this with the existing I-search implementation, or will I have to write it myself?

Comment: What version of emacs? In current upstrean, toggling symbol search, quitting the search and restarting it with `C-s C-s` brings back both the symbol and the option for further searching.

Comment: @NickD: Would you look at that. I'm still using Emacs 26.1 on this computer, but on another computer with 27.1 you are indeed right that it does repeat the search as I wanted it to. That's great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, starting from Emacs 27.1 this happens automatically.

The NEWS item is:

> *** Isearch now remembers the regexp-based search mode for words/symbols
> and case-sensitivity together with search strings in the search ring.

E.g. running `emacs -Q` and acting in the standard scratch buffer:

```
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.
```

Using <kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> `is` and then repeatedly typing <kbd>C-s</kbd> will cycle through only the two instances of the word `is`, skipping `Lisp` and `visit`.

If you then exit the isearch with <kbd>RET</kbd> (and/or any other editing) and then use <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> to repeat the previous search, it will again match only the two instances of the word `is`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `M-s .` for symbol search, and `M-p` and `M-n` for retrieving previous search strings (or if it is the first search, suggested search strings).

`M-s .` runs the command `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` (found in `global-map`), which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in `isearch.el`.

---

When in `minibuffer` use `M-p` and `M-n` to retrieve previous search terms.

`M-p` runs the command `isearch-ring-retreat` (found in `overriding-terminal-local-map`), which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in `isearch.el`.

---

`M-n` runs the command isearch-ring-advance (found in `overriding-terminal-local-map`), which is an interactive byte-compiled
Lisp function in `isearch.el`.

---

You can use `M-p` and `M-n` almost always in the minibuffer to retrieve historical items.  It works for simple search, as well as search and replace.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question that was asked - about repeating the same _type_ of search, rather than using the history of search _values_.